# DEBUG [GossipStage:1] 2018-02-08 17:36:07,897 FailureDetector.java:456 - Ignoring interval time of

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

The messages appear in debug.log file. The messages log in rate of about 1 per second on each node of the cluster (all 6 nodes that 3 nodes each in two data centers).

What is the reason for this message?

Answer (score 0):

The mail archive link will give you related answer : http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201705.mbox/%3CCANC-1ESusupohOn7zhnHDF+MdCZJtJowHrMBD4v_JoijeHWg6A@mail.gmail.com%3E

The gossiper module, always checks whether the nodes are up/ down, to do failure detection. The source code for this logs are from gossiper module: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/8b3a60b9a7dbefeecc06bace617279612ec7092d/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/gms/FailureDetector.java#L450-L474

Answer (score 0):

The `FailureDetector` is responsible of deciding if a node is considered UP or DOWN.

> The gossip process tracks state from other nodes both directly (nodes
>   gossiping directly to it) and indirectly (nodes communicated about
>   secondhand, third-hand, and so on). Rather than have a fixed threshold
>   for marking failing nodes, Cassandra uses an accrual detection
>   mechanism to calculate a per-node threshold that takes into account
>   network performance, workload, and historical conditions. During
>   gossip exchanges, every node maintains a sliding window of
>   inter-arrival times of gossip messages from other nodes in the
>   cluster.

Your node measures the acknowledgement latency for each gossip message sent to the other nodes when it is above the expected n `MAX_INTERVAL_IN_NANO` (2 sec) threshold  it will get reported.

If you take a look at the source code in the previous answer, you can see it is a DEBUG level message. It may be helpful in tracking down an actual issue causing the latency, but don't indicate a problem on their own.

Problems, which can cause this log message:

- Huge load on the node
- High pressure
- Bad network connection

You can also read some extra info about it [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9526?attachmentOrder=desc).